# How to get state updated after dispatch

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm new with react-native and redux and I want to know how can I get the state updated after the dispatch...

Follow my code:

**/LoginForm.js**

```
function mapStateToProps(state) { return { user: state.userReducer }; }

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    login: (username, password) => {      
      dispatch(login(username, password)); // update state loggedIn
    }
  }  
}

const LoginForm = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
export default LoginForm;
```

**/Login.js**
**---Here I've a button which calls this method loginOnPress()**

```
loginOnPress() {
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    this.props.login(username, password);
    console.log(this.props.user.loggedIn)
  }
```

According my code above, I call first the method **'this.props.login(username, password);'** that calls the dispatch and change the state '**loggedIn**'.

And after that I try to get the state updated but without success:

```
console.log(this.props.user.loggedIn)
```

Note: When I click the second time on this button the state comes updated

Comment: You should check for props changes in `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle hook, because when you check props on the next line after trying to set them, their changes have probably not propagated back to your component yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `this.props.login(username, password)` dispatches a login action on the redux-state.

Launching `store.getState()` will indeed immediately get you the redux-state after the update, but usually, you don't really need to do it because of the **redux `connect`** function that wraps your component.

The **redux `connect`** function updates your component with new props, so what you would usually do is "catch" these changes in one of the following functions of the [react lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html):

```
class Greeting extends React.Component {

  ...

  loginOnPress () {
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    this.props.login(username, password);
  }

  // before the new props are applied

  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps.user.loggedIn)
  }

  // just before the update

  componentWillUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log(nextProps.user.loggedIn)
  }

  // immediately after the update

  componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log(this.props.user.loggedIn)
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling dispatch will update the state immediately but your components will be updated a little bit later so you can use `componentWillReceiveProps` to react to changes in the props, you can have a look [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/291#issuecomment-185706321) for a better explanation of how state change works in React