# await a redux dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hello I would like to dispatch a login request. In this dispatch, I store the status of the loginattempt in the store as 'loginStatus'. After the dispatch I want to read the loginstatus and dispatch another action based off this value but the loginstatus is not updated by the time I try to access it. I added async await tags but the issue persists. Any way I can wait for a dispatch to complete before running the next lines of code? My current code is bellow

Thanks

```
handleSubmit = async () => {
    if( this.isValidForm() ) {
      const details = {
        "username": this.state.username,
        "password": this.state.password
      }
      await this.props.dispatch( login(details) )
      // setTimeout(console.log( this.props.loginStatus ), 4000)
      console.log(this.props.loginStatus)
      if( this.props.loginStatus !== SUCCESS ) this.props.dispatch( showAlert({ type: "error", message: "test"}))
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can if you use `redux-thunk` (doesn't work with `redux-saga`) and just return a promise - see the thunk docs

Comment: after a successful `login ` action, the state should be updated to reflect that, and the connected component can rerender accordingly

Comment: By default actions in Redux are dispatched synchronously, you can get redux store state right after dispatch using store.getState(), but usually, you don't really need to do it because of the redux connect function that wraps your component. Refer to this link for more details.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47235292/how-to-get-state-updated-after-dispatch/47238115

Comment: as you can see in my code i console.log this.props.loginstatus which the value in redux which should have been updated by my login dispatch. but the value has not been updated. I think you might be misunderstanding my issue? @bsapaka

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding my issue, my componenet uses the redux connect function. The store just isnt updating fast enough as I can see through my console.log directly after my login dispatch @Eric

Comment: @Tamjid I might need to see more code to understand your issue. (what does the action + reducer look like, where are you calling the login-request function, what does the selector/state-connection look like)